# I need a complete list of PowerShell commands for Windows server 2012 to troubleshoot windows server

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-server-2012

I need a complete list of PowerShell commands for Windows server 2012 to troubleshoot windows server.

Comment: Doesn't "help *" work?

Comment: Asking for *lists of things* is off topic.

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on your server is set up. According to the following URL if you use the following two commands it'll give you a listing of all available installed modules as well as their associated exported commands.

```
get-module
get-module –listAvailable
```

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/yungchou/2014/01/08/windows-server-2012-r2-installation-options-and-features-on-demand-part-3-of-5/

Comment: `Get-Command` is also a useful command for finding out what commands are available, and `Get-Help` can even tell the curious how to use them...